# Video on the webpage to autoplay after a set period of time using Javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a video tag on my website but it automaticly starts to play when the websites opens
this is indeed what I want, but I actually want it to start after about 5 seconds

is there a posibility to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with pure HTML but with JAVA Script you can use Timing events, 
With JavaScript, it is possible to execute some code at specified time-intervals. This is called timing events.

It's very easy to time events in JavaScript. The two key methods that are used are:
`setInterval()` - executes a function, over and over again, at specified time intervals
`setTimeout()` - executes a function, once, after waiting a specified number of milliseconds

Note that The setInterval() and setTimeout() are both methods of the HTML DOM Window object.

The setInterval() method will wait a specified number of milliseconds, and then execute a specified function, and it will continue to execute the function, once at every given time-interval.

```
window.setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);
```

The `window.setInterval()` method can be written without the window prefix.
The first parameter of set`Interval()` should be a function.
The second parameter indicates the length of the time-intervals between each execution.

here is an example to Alert hello every 3 seconds

```
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: I think this could do it, but I still don't know how I start the video in javascript, but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Well thats a totaly different question, so you may as well, award this one and close it.